# How can I download pdf file that is tired in my asset to local storage for all platform in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-chrome, web, mobile

I tried using html package but that is not supported on mobile device also I tried some other package but they were not supported on chrome

I expected that my pdf that I had provided in asset should be downloaded when the user click download button into their local storage irrespective of the platform they are using

Comment: What does "is tired in my asset" mean?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.